# Relationship between left identity and associativity

Tags: functional-programming

In an effort to better-grok monads I have reviewed many "Everything you need to know about Monads" tutorials out in the wild, but I feel like my understanding is still coming up a bit short.

While every one of the above faithfully recites the 3 laws of monads: right identity, left identity, and associativity along with their respective signatures (*which I understand*), the most prevalent deficit is a complete lack of *application*. That is, in practice, when creating a monadic structure, what are things that you can do *wrong* that will violate the 3 laws.

This brings us to my question. Given the following monad (TypeScript):

```
type Func<T, R> = (a: T) => R

export class Mutation<T extends number>
{
    constructor(readonly value: T) {}

    static unit<R extends number>(value: R)
    {
        let inValue = value;

        // the following line breaks right identity
        //inValue = inValue * inValue as R

        return new Mutation<R>(inValue);
    }

    flatMap(f: Func<T, Mutation<T>>): Mutation<T>
    {
        let inValue = this.value

        // the following line breaks left identity (but not associativity)
        //inValue = inValue * inValue as T

        let m = f(inValue)

        let outValue = m.value;

        // the following line breaks associativity (AND left identity)
        //outValue = outValue * outValue as T

        return new Mutation<T>(outValue)
    }
}
```

Embedded into the above monad are lines that can be un-commented to break the rules. Each of these lines is located in one of the 3 "regions" where "state" could be modified (thereby breaking the rules):

1. In the `unit` constructor
2. In `flatMap` *before* the function `f` is applied
3. In `flatMap` *after* the function `f` is applied

Now we can write a short script to verify each of the laws as follows:

```
let m = Mutation.unit(2 as number);

let f = (x: number) => Mutation.unit(x * x);

let g = (x: number) => Mutation.unit(x * x);

// assert that the creation of a new monad does not alter the value
let right = Mutation.unit(m.value).value === m.value

// assert that `flatMap` does not alter the wrapped value before or after it is passed to `f`
let left = f(m.value).value === m.flatMap(f).value

// assert that `flatMap` does not alter the wrapped value after it is passed to `f`
let assoc = m.flatMap(f).flatMap(g).value === m.flatMap((x) => f(x).flatMap(g)).value

console.log({right, left, assoc});
```

Here's my problem: I am able to produce results that look like:

```
{right: ..., left: false, assoc: true} // this is possible
{right: ..., left: false, assoc: false} // this is possible
```

but unable to produce a result like:

```
{right: ..., left: true, assoc: false} // this is not possible
```

That is, I cannot find a way to break the law of associativity that does not *also* break left identity. Said another way, my findings above indicate that it is possible to break left identity and preserve associativity, but not the other way around.

This leads me to conclude that associativity implies left identity and therefore the law of left identity is redundant. Clearly, this cannot be true or every tutorial/wiki is imprecise (which I find hard to believe).

How can I modify the monad above such that it breaks the law of associativity without also breaking the law of left identity?

To be clear, I believe I understand monads (as the abstraction of a strategy for combining computations). My question is really focused on the relationship between the laws of associativity and left identity. I would like to be shown that they are, in fact, independent. Specifically through modifying my example above if possible. But hey, if I'm misunderstanding some critical property I am also open to being corrected!

Comment: Not an answer to your questions, but you should probably also read "[the fallacy of monad tutorials](https://byorgey.wordpress.com/2009/01/12/abstraction-intuition-and-the-monad-tutorial-fallacy/)" and "[monads are like burritos](https://blog.plover.com/prog/burritos.html)" ;)

Comment: You should also watch Douglas Crockford's talk: [Monads and Gonads](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0EF0VTs9Dc).

Comment: I have a hunch that you have a hidden problem where each of your functions `f()`, `g()`, and the commented out lines all implement the same transformations. If you change implementations to perform different functions, you may be able to tease out where things are going wrong.

Comment: @BobDalgleish There could be something there... But I believe because chose the squaring operation it is not possible for two computations to converge to the same result by happenstance (every computation will produce a unique value). FWIW, I have tried various permutations of the script involving different computations as well as defining multiple `m` (`m1`, `m2`, etc) to test for this... to no avail.

Comment: @BobDalgleish Confirmed (to a reasonable level of confidence). Just changed every operation to be completely unique as well as 5 `m`'s to start (so none are reused). Same result. Also, FWIW its quite obvious when looking at the definition of the `left` statement that _any_ modification to the wrapped value with return `false`. We can also deduce (just by reasoning) that only modifications _after_ the function `f` is a applied will affect the `assoc` check. This is my issue. `assoc` and `left` do not appear to be independent.

Comment: `let right = Mutation.unit(m.value).value === m.value` - if I'm not mistaken, that's not quite what the monad laws say; rather, the rule is that, given a monadic value `m`, it should hold that the computational effect of `m.flatMap(Mutation.unit)` (however invoked), is the same as that of just `m` (i.e., one can be substituted for the other). Similarly, for left identity `Mutation.unit(value).flatMap(f)` should be equivalent to just `f(value)` (in the same sense as before). Each can be broken by unit or by flatMap for particular values (it should hold for *all* values).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Is it not the case that `m.flatMap(Muntation.unit)` can be rewritten to `Mutation.unit(m.value)`? Isn’t that exactly how it evaluates? More importantly, is my understanding that right identity essentially boils down to “the `unit` method _cannot_ alter the value” incorrect? That is, simply invoking the `unit` method to “lift” a value _must_ produce a Monad<T> that is logically equivalent T? I’m asking honestly. This is the point I’m trying to make about the deficits of these tutorials. They fail to convey the “essence” of these rules to me.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović To me it is far more instructive to provide an example of a rule being _broken_ than simply stated. My simple monad above is my attempt to illustrate _how_ one can fail to make a monad. As I see it, there are only 3 places (literally) in the code where logic can be inserted that may break the laws. It is my desire to understand, specifically, how changes in state (mutating `value`) affect these laws. My example above seems to indicate it is not possible for a monad to abide the law of left identity and fail associativity. This puzzles me greatly. Are they not independent?

Comment: @FilipMilovanović To muddy the waters further, it looks like the definition you provide above for left identity would imply right identity as well, where `f` = `Mutation.unit`, no? That would mean _both_ right identity and left identity are implied by associativity... If there isn’t some other “essence” at play here then we are left with only one rule...